# Count next item in array - foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have a wordpress foreach loop which gets category names.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($catnamea as $legname ) {
 $i++;
 echo $legname[$i].'<br>';
}
```

If i go $legname[0] - it will give me a category name, and as i up the numeber it lists all the other names. But id like this to happen without me having to enter another number, pertty much i want it to add a number on the variable $i for each item.

Here is the full code so you can see whats going on

```
    var pieData = [
                            <?php
                                $user_id = get_query_var('author');

                                $rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
                                //get all posts from author
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'author'=> $queried_object->ID
                                );

                                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

                                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                                        //put categories in array
                                        $cat = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
                                        $terms[] = $cat[0]->term_id;
                                        $catnames[] = $cat[0]->cat_name;

                                    endwhile;

                                    wp_reset_query();
                                endif;

                                //count matching categories (array vals)
                                $countVal = array_count_values($terms);
                                $colors = array();
                                $catnames[] = array();
                                foreach($countVal as $count){

                                    $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];

                                    echo "  {
                                            value: ".$count.",
                                            color:'".$color."'
                                            },";
                                            $colors[] = $color;
                                            $catnamea[] = $catnames;


                                }

                            ?>
                            ]

                            var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("piec").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
                        </script>
                        <?php
                        foreach($colors as $scolor) {
                            echo '<div style="background:'.$scolor.';height:5px; width:5px;float:left"></div>';
                        }
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach($catnamea as $legname ) {
                        $i++;
                            echo $legname[$i].'<br>';
                        } ?>
```

Comment: You want to do it without that `$i++` ?

Comment: Currently the $i++ is buggy, is not working correctly, pulling in the same result more than once

Comment: Now this is strange considering that `i` may never repeat. Did you checked your array ?

Comment: what if you place the $legname in another foreach loop, would that work?

Comment: I know very little about php how would i place legname in another foreach, whould i have to state the array there also

Comment: Can I check what you want to do?  You just want to dump the contents of `$catnamea`, with `<br>` after each entry?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you're confusing the array variable (`$catnamea`) with the loop variable (`$legname`).

Try something like this:

```
foreach($catnamea as $legname ) {
    echo $legname.'<br>';
}
```

or, if you really need the index, you could do something like

```
foreach($catnamea as $index => $legname ) {
    echo $catnamea[$index].'<br>';
}
```

though in your example I can't see the advantage.  You could use `$i` the same way you did in your example for this, but that makes assumptions array keys (ie that they start at 1 and increment by 1 each time) that may always not be true.

Something like:

```
if (!empty($catnamea)) {
    echo implode('<br>', $catnamea) . '<br>';
}
```

should also do what you're after.

If you want the total number of elements in the array, you can just use `count($catnamea);`.  No need to increment a variable as you go through the loop.